# Laravel Table Relation One to Many not work using InfyOm Generator

Tags: laravel

I working on a project with laravel using a generator called infyom lab(its new to me). I had new experience with this generator and an error. Its says "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object". I get used to do it all manually without generator and doin fine. Hoping some help

UserController.php

```
public function index(Request $request) {
$users = $this->userRepository->all();
return view('users.index')
->with('users', $users);
}
```

UserRepository

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Repositories\BaseRepository;
/**
* Class UserRepository
* @package App\Repositories
* @version August 7, 2019, 5:11 pm UTC
*/
class UserRepository extends BaseRepository
{
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fieldSearchable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'telephone',
    'username',
    'password',
    'company_id'
];
/**
 * Return searchable fields
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getFieldsSearchable()
{
    return $this->fieldSearchable;
}
/**
 * Configure the Model
 **/
public function model()
{
    return User::class;
}
}
```

Model User

```
public function company(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
```

Model Company

```
public function users(){
return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

View User

```
<td>{{ $user->company->name }}</td>
```

Comment: How is `$this->userRepository` defined in your controller? Also, you should avoid using `{!! !!}` and use `{{ }}` instead unless you really need the raw input. Property of non-object suggests `$user->company` evaluates to `null`.

Comment: `$this->userRepository` is from generator called infyom, {!! !!} is from generator too 
 and it work fine.That the question, why it says null?

Comment: `{!! !!}` doesn't escape input. `{{ }}` does. It transforms `<` and `>` signs to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. It says `null` because the `User` is not associated to any `Company` (`$user->company_id` is either `null` or not a valid `Company` id)

Comment: okay i fix the `{!! !!}` thing, thats my title btw, did i miss something?

Comment: did you try `dd($user);` or `dd($user->company);` to see if its have a value about company? or `dd($user->company());`

Comment: As I stated, your user doesn't have a company. Check `$user->company_id` 's value.

Comment: the `dd($user)` is work fine but the `dd($user->company);` say `null`

Comment: `dd($user->company_id)` has value

Comment: Is there a Company with the same id than `$user->company_id`?

Comment: i use increment for the id, so there arent no same id, i check it also

Comment: That is not the problem. If `dd(\App\Company::find($user->company_id))` is `null` then, the user is not associated to any Company that exists in your database.

Comment: i try `$users = $this->userRepository->all();
        foreach ($users as $key) {
            dd(User::find($key->company_id));
        }` and i got data

Comment: `Company::find`. We're looking for the `Company`

Comment: `dd(Company::find(1));` is exist

Comment: Then I do not know. Unless the repositories are not updating correctly I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: Me too, i get used to do all project manually but this time i got stuck on this generator

Answer (score 0):

The Solution for This Problem is To write relation `hasMany` and `belongsTo` in `Model` that inside Model Folder `app\Models`, not on `app\`.

Comment: Laravel has a User model into `app` folder directly, while InfyOm Laravel Generator generates Models under `app/Models` directory. Because in large projects, that's a better way to organize all the models.
You can configure it from the config file. so just check that and I think you should be ready to go. If that's creating error then either move the User model to the `app/Models` or just change the configuration in the config file to generate models into directly `app` folder.